# Using a resistance band to work the upper back -- not working

Tags: exercise

I want to work my upper back to help fix my hunched "computer posture" shoulders.  I'm sitting with my legs extended, wrapping the band around my feet, and pulling the handles of the band to my torso.  I did 65 reps yesterday, some with my elbows bending downward, some with them bending out.  Today, I'm not sore!  What gives?  Is there a more efficient exercise for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your statement I understand that you did some sort of rowing motion. Since rowing is a motion where the lats are involved as major muscles, probably the resistence was not big enough.

To your posture fix I would rather recommend band pull aparts:
[Picture showing the motion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdlGz.jpg)

and rotator cuff exercises.

Here are some clips showing the exercises:
https://youtu.be/A-MZOdHH3Nc
and
https://youtu.be/l2VQ_WZ8Bto

I would also recommend working in multiple sets of 15-20 reps, instead of one all-out set.

Comment: It looks like these exercises focus on the front of the shoulder and maybe even chest?  Those are the tight muscles that are causing my shoulders to cave inward.  I need to find a way to work the upper back.

Comment: You are wrong, pulling from the front to back is involving the back muscles. If you would put the band on your back and pull to front it would be the front muscles!

Comment: Thank you -- so those don't work the front of the shoulders, but the back then?

Comment: Yes correct. Only the back

Comment: I've been trying these exercises and it seems like when I do pull aparts (as shown in your jpg), after the set I feel fatigue in the front of my shoulders.  Could I be doing this simple exercise wrong?  Edit: http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/band-pull-apart shows that they do indeed work the front shoulder.  This muscle is tense (pulling my shoulders forward) and I think I want to avoid working them?

Comment: You know, you asked a question and I give you the exercises that are applying  to your issue. The body is complex and you will NEVER isolate one specific muscle group. The body is simply not working in that way. Maybe your shoulder is getting tight, but you are working 95% the muscles of your back. Watch the videos and if still in doubt I recommend seeing a doc to identify what problems you realy have and continue working on it. I cant say anything in further detail if I cant see what you are doing and look like (posture) ... good luck.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I'll try these out for a few days then accept the answer.

Comment: Sure, dont forget to stretch additionally and take your time. I had same issues and could barely lift my right arm to a 90% angle... without pain.

Answer (score 1):

Soreness is not an indicator of effectiveness.

Bands do not provide the most strenuous resistance.

A more efficient exercise to work the upper back would involve pulling and bracing exercises using dumbbells, a barbell, or a pull-up bar, or something that can be jury-rigged into a pull-up bar. For instance, rows, pull-ups, or deadlifts. Proper shoulder retraction and depression during certain yoga poses (e.g. down dog, or its more vigorous relative, the Hindu push-up) could assist as well, but I find best return on time/effort investment from heavier exercises.

Comment: A band is what I have access to.

Comment: @horsehair Unfortunately that doesn't mean they'll be effective for your purposes. Can you gain access to dumbbells, or a pull-up bar, or something that can be jury-rigged into a pull-up bar? See "What if I don’t have a gym?" at http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/11/06/inverted-row-are-you-missing-out-on-this-great-exercise/

Comment: Depending on the type of bands ;-) - I use some of Iron Woody (monster) with 200 lbs of resistence for good mornings. I doubt anyone could do some pull aparts with them .. lol